# wifi cracking WEP with macbook vmware and backtrack 5r1

Tags: wireless-networking, security, vmware, osx-lion, backtrack

Im trying to crack the WEP on my personal router. I have a macbook with osx lion airport extreme that has backtrack 5 in a VM. I have heard of kismac but currently it doesn't work well with lion. What is my best option to crack this wep by tomorrow?

SOLVED:
"had to install vmware tools to load the right drivers for the wireless card within the virtual machine."

Comment: The user has a legitimate purpose, as he/she owns the router.  I am not voting to close.

Comment: yes I intend to do this on my own router  and I am writing a paper for school on wireless security and need to demonstrate with screen shots . I am thinking about just rolling back to OSX snow leopard and using kismac, since I can't get backtrack to work right with airport extreme.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to crack the WEP key on your router would be to factory reset it (if you also don't have the login details), then reconfigure it with a key that you know.

I would recommend using WPA this time.

Comment: +1: That's the only "legitimate" answer. :)

Comment: @techie007 It wasn't just about legitimacy, there are countless wep cracking tutorials online, and if these weren't any help, it was unlikely SU assistance would have resolved it in the timescale specified :)

Comment: alright, thought I'd give it a try. sorry.